# Recursive function to remove null values from mongoose Object based on separate object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, recursion, mongoose

I'm building an API using nodejs, express and mongoDB through mongoose.  I would like to set things up so that when a PUT call is made to update a document, if `null` is passed for a field, that field is then removed, otherwise, whatever is passed will be saved.  I have been able to make this work fine as long as the documents have no subdocuments or arrays. It's when there are multiple levels within the data that I'm having trouble.

I found this recursive function that will remove all null values from an object and then return that updated object:

```
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
    (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(obj[key]) ||
    (obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === null) && delete obj[key]
  );
  return obj;
};
```

However, this only works for removing properties of the same object.  What I need to be able to do is run this function on one object, while removing the correct corresponding properties on the other object. And I don't even know where to begin with that, unfortunately.  My head already starts to spin a bit just with a simple recursive function like the one above.

I've tried to first update the mongoose object returned from a find by comparing it to the data passed in the API call, and then running that updated mongoose object through the `removeEmpty` function above. But mongoose ignores any null or empty string properties passed, and any mongoose object I try to run though the same function always results in a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Ideally, I'd like a universal function that I can pass all update call data to the API through, but I'm open to just about any solution at this point.

Here's an example of the data that would be sent to the API:

```
{
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "firstName": "First",
  "lastName": "",
  "address": {
    "line1": "123 Test St.",
    "line2": null
  }
}
```

And here's what I would like the end result to look like in MongoDB

```
{
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "firstName": "First",
  "lastName": "",
  "address": {
    "line1": "123 Test St."
  }
}
```

Edit: I realized that I didn't include what the mongoose object might look like.  Here is an example:

```
{
  "_id": "5e31fe773cd8481cbf6c0ebb",
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "firstName": "First",
  "lastName": "Last",
  "address": {
    "line1": "987 Example Blvd.",
    "line2": "Ste. 1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to compare objects? It seems like you just need to update the data, yea?

Comment: What if you replace `null` with `undefined` when saving the document?

Comment: So I probably failed to explain myself well.   I need to compare the two because I am somewhat limited in how I can manipulate the mongoose object.  Yes, changing `null` to `undefined` does remove that property from the object, however, I need to be able to use the `data ` object in order to know which properties I need to set to `undefined` in the mongoose object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
    "email": "user@domain.com",
    "firstName": "First",
    "lastName": "",
    "address": {
      "line1": "123 Test St.",
      "line2": null
    }
  }
  
const mongoose = {
  "_id": "5e31fe773cd8481cbf6c0ebb",
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "firstName": "First",
  "lastName": "Last",
  "address": {
    "line1": "987 Example Blvd.",
    "line2": "Ste. 1"
  }
}
  function makeUndefined(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.entries(obj1).reduce((output,[key,val]) => {
        if(val) output[key] = typeof val === "object" ? makeUndefined(val,obj2[key]) : val;
        if(obj2[key] === null) output[key] = undefined;
        return output;
    },{})
  }
  
  function removeNull(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((output,[key,val]) => {
        if(val) output[key] = typeof val === "object" ?  removeNull(val) : val;   
        return output;
    },{})
  }
  
  console.log(makeUndefined(mongoose,data))
  console.log(removeNull(data));
```

Comment: I don't really see how this function is really any different from the function I posted, but I surely could be missing something.  Could you provide a bit of explanation?

Comment: so you're trying to change the mongoose object to undefined where the data object property was removed for being null? See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer would strip all falsy values and would not work properly with nested arrays.

```js
const data = {
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "firstName": "First",
  "lastName": "",
  "address": {
    "line1": "123 Test St.",
    "line2": null
  },
  "array" : [null, 2, [null]]
}

class ObjectId {} // Types.ObjectId in 'mongoose'
const remove = ['__v']

function sanitize(obj) {
  if (obj === null || obj instanceof ObjectId) return;
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.map(sanitize);
  if (typeof obj === 'object')
    return Object.entries(
      obj instanceof Document ? obj.toObject() : obj,
    ).reduce((output, [key, val]) => {
      if (!remove.includes(key))
        output[key] =
          typeof val === 'object' ? sanitize(val) : val;
      return output;
    }, {});
  return obj;
}

console.info(sanitize(data));
```

TS version:

```js
function sanitize<T = any>(obj: T): any {
  if (obj === null || obj instanceof Types.ObjectId) return;
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.map(sanitize);
  return Object.entries(obj instanceof Document ? obj.toObject() : obj).reduce(
    (output, [key, val]) => {
      if (!['__v', 'shopperId'].includes(key))
        output[key as keyof typeof output] =
          typeof val === 'object' ? sanitize(val) : val;
      return output;
    },
    {} as T,
  );
}
```